# Possible to have a tab char in Adaptive card?

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Is there any way to put a tab in a text block?

I know that for line breaks you have to do `\n\n`.
I tried doing that with tabs, i.e.

```
{
    "type": "TextBlock",
    "text": "This is some \t\ttext",
    "size": "large"
},
```

expecting this to render as
`This is some    text`
but it just comes as `This is some text`

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: We see that using `&emsp;` is giving tab space only in [adaptivecards.io](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/). The same is not giving any tab space in App studio or through code. We are checking this internally.

Comment: We raised a bug and the team is looking into it.

Comment: In the meantime I ended up getting result somewhat in line with what I wanted using a FactSet

Comment: We got an update from the engineering team saying, Teams don't support any free html content by design, so "&emsp;" rendering as plain text is expected.

Comment: Well, I never said we tried using `&emsp;`. We tried using `\t\t`. What is the logic behind `\n\n`working, and `\t\t` not working?

Answer (score 0):

We got an update from the engineering team that only the escape sequences mentioned in the document are supported. Please check [Newlines for Adaptive Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#newlines-for-adaptive-cards) to see what all escape sequences are allowed.